# AWS S3: can I recover pointers to accidentally deleted Glaciered data?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, recovery, amazon-glacier

In the bucket that we use we have a set of "folders" and "subfolders", e.g.

```
my-bucket:data/foo/
my-bucket:data/bar/
```

We had automatic Glacier backup of this data up until recently. More recently, someone accidentally overwrote the top `data` folder resulting in loss of all our data there. The obvious question is whether any of that data can be recovered. More specifically, is there a way -- maybe with help of AWS support -- to restore the Glaciered-up data? My hope is that what we really lost is just pointers to that data that might still exist somewhere and might be recovered. Or am I too optimistic?

Whatever recovery operation can be done -- is it by any chance doable programmatically using `boto`?

Comment: In Glacier you create a Vault and then you create archives within that Vault.  Are you saying the Vault was deleted?  Or the archives?  Or are you saying that the live data in S3 was deleted?  Its not clear to me from your description.

Comment: @garnaat The bucket on S3 was set up to perform auto backup to Glacier after X days. Then the whole "folder" `data` on S3 got deleted. I am hoping that when a file on S3 gets backed up, it gets handled by AWS "under the hood" differently than an S3 file that is not backed up so that when an accidental deletion of the corresponding S3 key happens, the data can still be retrieved somehow. Since I was suing the auto backup feature of S3, I did not have to interact with Glacier directly by creating vaults etc.

Comment: You should be okay.  If you go to the AWS Management Console and go to the S3 Console, select the bucket in question and then select "Initiate Restore", what do you see?

Comment: @garnaat The "initiate restore" option is disabled (grayed out)

Comment: You probably want to contact AWS support for something like this.